# tableau filter based on two dimensions

Tags: tableau-api

My Data:

```
dim1,dim2
a, 1
a, 2
a, 3
b, 1
b, 2
b, 2
```

I want to have two filters, both with options `1,2,3`.

The first filter filters: `if dim1 = a or (dim1 = b & dim2 = select 1,2,3)`

While the second filters: `if dim1 = b or (dim1 = a & dim2 = select 1,2,3)`

Where `select 1,2,3` are the options in the filter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you would use either of them, correct? because if you used both filters, it would show all records since the first condition will always be true.
Are you able to select only one numerical value or several?

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter for choosing 1,2 3 and reference that parameter in calculated fields with your conditions. Put the calculated fields on the filter shelf